# Set widget defaults when making composite widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I have been learning Kivy, and am currently working on my first app. I've made a new widget `PicButton` from the `Image` widget and the mixin `ButtonBehavior` like so:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class PicButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):

    def on_press(self):
        print("Pressed")

    def on_release(self):
        print("Released")
```

Now for all instances of `PicButton`, I want the `allow_stretch` variable set to `True` and the `keep_ratio` variable set to `False`. I tried to overload the constructor to accomplish this,

```
def __init__(self):
    return super(Image, self).__init__(allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, **kwargs)
```

but it doesn't work. Is overloading a constant of one of my imported classes possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to overload properties in whatever `.kv` file you are using. Like so:

```
<PicButton>
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: False
```

By putting the name of your widget between `<>`, you are defining how that widget should be implemented in all cases.